# How to match json path in Hoverfly matching strategy?

Tags: json, handlebars.js, jsonpath, templating, hoverfly

The jsonPath matching in hoverfly simulation file is

```
"body" : [ { "matcher" : "jsonpath", "value" : "$[0].langId" }
```

The above does not seem to work for the following request

```
"Body": "[{\"langId\":\"en\",\"fallback\":\"true\"}]"
```

Is this an issue ? How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused due to a [bug](https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly/issues/895) in Hoverfly v1.1.3 where the JSONpath does not work.

Fixed in v1.1.4 of Hoverfly